# Jquery won't count checkbox when checked first time

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a problem with my Jquery script, it has to count the checked boxes, but it won't count on the first time clicked, so i have check-uncheck-check again in order to count. It counts correctly only in firefox`

> ```
>    $("#collapseOne input[type=checkbox]").click(function( event ) {  
>     var max = 3;  
>     var checkboxes = $('#collapseOne
>     input[type="checkbox"]');
>
>   checkboxes.change(function(){
>       var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;  $( "#col1" ).text(current);
>       checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max); });
> ```

http://jsfiddle.net/nm8T9/

Comment: I cant understand what exactly you need? plz explain ...

Comment: Be more specific about what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: I want the jquery code to count, if the checkbox is checked. At the moment when i click on the checkbox, first time nothing happens, when i uncheck and check again, then it counts. But i need the jquery code to count it on the first time, when a checkbox is checked. Don't use firefox when testing, becuase for some reason , it works in firefox.

Comment: @WalterMacambira That question was pretty specific if you read the question then look at the code.

Comment: @Nunners Not for me and not for Hassan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to have a click handler

```
var max = 3;
var checkboxes = $("#collapseOne input[type=checkbox]");
checkboxes.change(function(){
    var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
    $( "#col1" ).text(current) ;
    checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r3zk4/)

Look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r3zk4/2/)

Your click handler will result in the registering `no-of-clicks - 1` change handler executions

Comment: More specifically, the reason it wasn't working until after the first click, is because you were adding the change event when it's clicked.  So it needs to be clicked before the handler starts firing.

Answer (score 0):

You are registering the `change` event inside the click handler, this will not be automatically executed, you should assign the `change` event handler on DOM Ready.

jQuery : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/T4Su9/2/)

```
var max = 3;
var checkboxes = $("#collapseOne input[type=checkbox]");
checkboxes.change(function(){
    var current = checkboxes.filter(':checked').length;
    $( "#col1" ).text(current) ;
    checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)').prop('disabled', current >= max);
});
```